# TFS Issue: No source control options (get latest, check-out, check-in) for Solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs, orchardcms, azure-devops

**Background**

I created a new project with Microsoft's Team Foundation Service (tfs.visualstudio.com). I added code (Orchard CMS) which includes the solution file and performed initial check-in. To make sure nothing was missed, I removed mappings and deleted my local. Then got latest and reestablished mappings. I opened the solution, built it and set up a local site. Everything worked fine.

**Issue**

Whenever I open/load the solution, I noticed that I don't have the usual TFS options like get latest, check-out and check-in and source control options. Then I noticed an add to source control option (see below)

[image]

Whenever I click on it, I get told that the *'item 'Orchard.sln' is already under source control'*

Without source control, I don't have the options and I can't track which files have been updated or not, and the locks as well. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the source control settings are in the SLN file.

Open it up with notepad, and remove the following `GlobalSection` (there can be more than one sometimes):

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    ...Stuff...
EndGlobalSection
```

Now re-bind the solution and project using the: File, Source Control, Advanced, Change Source Control... option.

This should setup the binding correctly. If you check in these changes to SLN, vspcc, csproj files it will stay.

Comment: In my version of VS (2010 Pro), there is no "Advanced" mid-menu stage.

Comment: Czech http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459016/how-can-i-rebind-my-project-in-tfs

Comment: @DaveShaw, any idea if it is a Web Site project (as opposed to Web App project), where the TFS bindings get stored at the proj level (since there is no csproj file).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. When I opened a  file in solution explorer and modified it, it was being checked out.

I fixed it by unbinding my solution and projects and then rebinding them.

To unbind:

(1) selecting my solution in solution explorer
(2) selecting File -> Source Control Advanced -> Change Source Control
(3) clicking unbind for my solution and all projects
(4) click OK

To bind:
(1) selecting my solution in solution explorer
(2) selecting File -> Source Control Advanced -> Change Source Control
(3) clicking bind my solution and all projects
(4) click OK

These files will appear under Pending Changes. After I checked them in,, I tested if it worked.

I went to solution explorer, opened one of my .cs files, went to an end of line of code hit enter, and noticed it immediately got checked out.

I didn't have to open my solution in notepad and delete anything as mentioned in another answer.

NOTE: I am using VS 2012 Pro and TFS 2010.